# Editing block content: empty block body

Tags: blocks

I've been asked to support a drupal website. The website has a block that has content in it. When I locate the block in /admin/structure/block/block-content, the "block body" section is empty. I am at loss and have no idea where to find the block content. I have no access to the database to edit the block content directly there.

Comment: It might have been added via template file. In your codebase, `/themes/your_theme/templates` see if there is a template file for that block.

Comment: @NoSssweat That seems to be exactly it, thank you!